# How do I set the pageloadtimeout in Cypress?

Tags: cypress

How do I set the pageloadtimeout in the cypress.config.js file? There is this link [Documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration), but I am not sure where to place the pageloadtimeout in the file.

I have tried pasting it in the file and it gave me errors. I think it was because I didn't place it in the right place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you search the page for `pageLoadTimeout`, the first instance comes up in the section **Global** (see the page index on the right).

That means you place the option outside the `e2e` or `component` section.

```js
const { defineConfig } = require('cypress')

module.exports = defineConfig({
  pageLoadTimeout: 70_000,
  e2e: {
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:1234'
  }
})
```